# Locked DataGridView. Linq is a problem?

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, datagridview

I get the collection from webservice:

```
var allPlaceHolders =
    from ph in new MyService().GetPlaceHolders()
    select new { Code = ph.Code, Name = ph.Name, Related = false };

dgPlaceHoldersAdd.DataSource = allPlaceHolders.ToList();
```

Designer.cs:

```
this.dgPlaceHoldersAdd.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode =
    System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
this.dgPlaceHoldersAdd.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 54);
this.dgPlaceHoldersAdd.Name = "dgPlaceHoldersAdd";
this.dgPlaceHoldersAdd.RowHeadersVisible = false;
this.dgPlaceHoldersAdd.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(286, 151);
this.dgPlaceHoldersAdd.TabIndex = 15;
```

The problem is, that  I can't changing value of checkBox column.

I has enabled AutoGeneratedColumns (In datagridview at start there is not any column)

ADDED:

This works funny:
At first click id doesn't change value of checkbox column. 
At second work, and then start to work fine.

But...when I clicked at another row then row before change his values

It works like radiobutton...

```
 private void dgPlaceHoldersAdd_CellMouseUp(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
        {


            if (e.ColumnIndex == 2 && e.RowIndex > -1)
            {
                dgPlaceHoldersAdd.ReadOnly = false;
                dgPlaceHoldersAdd.CurrentRow.Cells[2].ReadOnly = false;

                 //dgPlaceHoldersAdd.EndEdit();

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You create an anonymous object in your LINQ query. The classes C# generated behind the cover are immutable (=readonly). This means that your DataGridView can not change its value.

Try creating a custom object that is mutable and create that from within your LINQ query.